# Using Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat to generate PDF properly

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I want to export to pdf all the sheets on the workbook except the first one. To do that I used Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat instead of ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat.

The problem using Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat, is that for each sheet, the only part of it that will appear ond the correspondent pdf page is a manual selection instead of all the printing area as it should be (if I select only one cell it will be the only one that appears on the pdf). Using ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat the pdf is generated as intended.

```
Sub PDF()
    Dim SaveAsStr As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim ArraySh(2 To Sheets.Count)

    For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
        ArraySh(i) = Sheets(i).Name
    Next

...

    'ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=SaveAsStr & ".pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Sheets(ArraySh).Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=SaveAsStr & ".pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

How can I use the Selection method, to generate the PDF properly?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796286/use-a-method-on-multiple-sheets-simultaneously-without-using-activesheet-or-sele) out for a possible workaround.