# Saving a File as PDF using the file name and a specific file path

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm new to VBA and trying to create a macro that will automatically save my file as a PDF file using the file's base name. This topic has been covered quite a bit in various sites so I was able to get most of the code I needed but for some reason I'm getting tripped up in the very last statement. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()

Dim SaveDirectory As String
Dim SaveFileName As String
Dim BaseName As String
Dim fso

SaveDirectory = Environ("Userprofile") & "\Dropbox\Operations\VBA Projects\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

BaseName = fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)

SaveFileName = SaveDirectory & BaseName & ".pdf"

Sheets(Array("Page1", "Page2")).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                              FileName:=SaveFileName, _
                                              Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                              IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                              IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                              OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

When I debug through the whole code, that last statement gets highlighted. Not sure what I"m doing wrong.

Comment: What error does it throw when it highlights the line?

Comment: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method does not work directly with an array of sheets.

The below will work *(it's one of the rare cases where `Select` and `Activate` are necessary in Excel VBA)*.

```
Sheets(Array("Page1", "Page2")).Select
Sheets("Page1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                              FileName:=SaveFileName, _
                                              Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                              IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                              IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                              OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: It works just fine for me without the activate statement - I was just about to post a very similar answer to yours :) Maybe because I use fully qualified references? ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Page1", "Page2")).Select

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Scott. I concur with Miqi that the Activate statement is not needed.

Comment: [Select and Activate are not even required if you only want to print a range of sheets in the Workbook.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36107539/4088852)

Comment: @Comintern - bear in mind that the link you provided uses the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method on an **an entire workbook**, as opposed to only selected sheets (granted I do see the work around to only use certain sheets within the workbook.).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - That's my point - you don't have to use `Select` if you use a higher level object.

Comment: @Comintern - it's a valid point, but I also think its worth knowing how to do both ways - as there may be complications in a workbook structure that make it easier to the method on selected sheets only.